# How to invoke a non-static method by reflection without creating new instance in same class?

Tags: java, reflection

I know how to invoke a method by reflection, it creates a new instance. But I can't do that. Because my class impelemented Runnable interface, I have to start run method in a new thread. So this is not desired.
My code now is:

```
public class Validation () impelements Runnable {
  Validation (String[] methodName) {
    if(methodName[2].equals("deposit") ){
        this.deposit(account);
    }
    else if (methodName[2].equals("withdraw") ){
        this.withdraw(account);
    } 
    // lots of if-else
}
//..... other methods , deposit() , withdraw() , run();
}
```

I need something like this (without creating a new instance of class but it should be reflection) :

**UPDATE** :

if-else should replace with something like this:

```
try {
this.invoke(methodName[2] , account);
} catch (Exceotion ex){
 // something
}
```

**I can't use static deposit or withdraw methods, they are using non-static variables.**

In **php** we have simething like this:

```
$methodName = $array[2] ;
$this.methodName();
```

***My question is :***

How to invoke a non-static method by reflection without creating new instance in same class?

Comment: You cannot. It's impossible. You need an instance to invoke instance methods.

Comment: You can't do that. Just think about it - how can you invoke an object method (which can modify its state) without the object?

Comment: Are you asking how to invoke a method by reflection on an _existing_ object?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You say _"I know how to invoke a method by reflection"_, which works just fine with an already existing object.  There's no need to "create a new object".

Comment: @JimGarrison please see again, I've changed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

Just think about it, non-static methods are linked with objects of the class, rather then with the class itself.

So, to invoke them you need instance of class.

It would be another matter though, if you want to invoke a non-static method with reflection, but without instantiating, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling omitted for clarity

```
class ObjectThatImplementsFoo {
    public void foo() {
    }
}

public void invokeFooOnObject(ObjectThatImplementsFoo foo) {
   Method m = foo.getClass().getMethod("foo");
   m.invoke(foo, null);
}
```

So your "if-else" should be replaced with something more like this:

```
try {
    Method m = this.getClass().getMethod(methodName[2], account.getClass());
    m.invoke(this, account);
} catch (Exception ex){
 // something
}
```